# Stripe flutter error: Unable to infer complex closure return type; add explicit type to disambiguate

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, android-studio, flutter-stripe

I just started getting this issue after adding flutter stripe package while running the app. I can't figure out why this issue coming again and again. I tried several solutions  including pod install several times deleting pod lock file and pod folder. My xcode version is 13.2.1 and flutter is 3.0.0.

```
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    Writing result bundle at path:
        /var/folders/s3/qg6_sd_x7v9c5p0xzgwd3sjr0000gn/T/flutter_tools.J74G6G/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirNRJtwQ/temporary_xcresult_bundle

    /Users/apple/StudioProjects/test2/ios/Pods/StripePayments/StripePayments/StripePayments/Source/Internal/API Bindings/APIRequest.swift:56:42: error: variable binding in a condition requires an initializer
                    guard let responseObject else {
                                             ^
    /Users/apple/StudioProjects/test2/ios/Pods/StripePayments/StripePayments/StripePayments/Source/Internal/API Bindings/APIRequest.swift:98:42: error: variable binding in a condition requires an initializer
                    guard let responseObject else {
                                             ^
    /Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fsxrcxlpwvnsjwaxkmmacfdixrme/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/StripePayments.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Analytic+Payments.dia:1:1: warning: Could not read serialized diagnostics file: error("Invalid diagnostics signature") (in target 'StripePayments' from project 'Pods')
    Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
    /Users/apple/StudioProjects/test2/ios/Pods/StripePayments/StripePayments/StripePayments/Source/Internal/API Bindings/APIRequest.swift:56:42: error: variable binding in a condition requires an initializer
                    guard let responseObject else {
                                             ^
    /Users/apple/StudioProjects/test2/ios/Pods/StripePayments/StripePayments/StripePayments/Source/Internal/API Bindings/APIRequest.swift:98:42: error: variable binding in a condition requires an initializer
                    guard let responseObject else {
                                             ^
    /Users/apple/StudioProjects/test2/ios/Pods/StripePayments/StripePayments/StripePayments/Source/Internal/API Bindings/APIRequest.swift:56:42: error: variable binding in a condition requires an initializer
                    guard let responseObject else {
                                             ^
    /Users/apple/StudioProjects/test2/ios/Pods/StripePayments/StripePayments/StripePayments/Source/Internal/API Bindings/APIRequest.swift:98:42: error: variable binding in a condition requires an initializer
                    guard let responseObject else {
                                             ^
    /Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fsxrcxlpwvnsjwaxkmmacfdixrme/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/StripePayments.build/Objects-normal/arm64/NSDecimalNumber+Stripe_Currency.dia:1:1: warning: Could not read serialized diagnostics file: error("Invalid diagnostics signature") (in target 'StripePayments' from project 'Pods')
    Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
    /Users/apple/StudioProjects/test2/ios/Pods/StripePayments/StripePayments/StripePayments/Source/Internal/API Bindings/APIRequest.swift:56:42: error: variable binding in a condition requires an initializer
                    guard let responseObject else {
                                             ^
    /Users/apple/StudioProjects/test2/ios/Pods/StripePayments/StripePayments/StripePayments/Source/Internal/API Bindings/APIRequest.swift:98:42: error: variable binding in a condition requires an initializer
                    guard let responseObject else {
                                             ^
    /Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fsxrcxlpwvnsjwaxkmmacfdixrme/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/StripePayments.build/Objects-normal/arm64/STPAPIClient+ApplePay.dia:1:1: warning: Could not read serialized diagnostics file: error("Invalid diagnostics signature") (in target 'StripePayments' from project 'Pods')
    Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
    /Users/apple/StudioProjects/test2/ios/Pods/StripePayments/StripePayments/StripePayments/Source/Internal/API Bindings/APIRequest.swift:56:42: error: variable binding in a condition requires an initializer
                    guard let responseObject else {
                                             ^
    /Users/apple/StudioProjects/test2/ios/Pods/StripePayments/StripePayments/StripePayments/Source/Internal/API Bindings/APIRequest.swift:98:42: error: variable binding in a condition requires an initializer
                    guard let responseObject else {
                                             ^
    /Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fsxrcxlpwvnsjwaxkmmacfdixrme/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/StripePayments.build/Objects-normal/arm64/STPBankAccount.dia:1:1: warning: Could not read serialized diagnostics file: error("Invalid diagnostics signature") (in target 'StripePayments' from project 'Pods')
    Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
    /Users/apple/StudioProjects/test2/ios/Pods/StripePayments/StripePayments/StripePayments/Source/Internal/API Bindings/APIRequest.swift:56:42: error: variable binding in a condition requires an initializer
                    guard let responseObject else {
                                             ^
    /Users/apple/StudioProjects/test2/ios/Pods/StripePayments/StripePayments/StripePayments/Source/Internal/API Bindings/APIRequest.swift:98:42: error: variable binding in a condition requires an initializer
                    guard let responseObject else {
                                             ^
    /Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fsxrcxlpwvnsjwaxkmmacfdixrme/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/StripePayments.build/Objects-normal/arm64/STPBankAccountParams.dia:1:1: warning: Could not read serialized diagnostics file: error("Invalid diagnostics signature") (in target 'StripePayments' from project 'Pods')
    Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
    /Users/apple/StudioProjects/test2/ios/Pods/StripePayments/StripePayments/StripePayments/Source/PaymentHandler/STPPaymentHandler.swift:301:28: error: variable binding in a condition requires an initializer
                guard let self else {
                               ^
    /Users/apple/StudioProjects/test2/ios/Pods/StripePayments/StripePayments/StripePayments/Source/PaymentHandler/STPPaymentHandler.swift:520:28: error: variable binding in a condition requires an initializer
                guard let self else {
                               ^
    /Users/apple/StudioProjects/test2/ios/Pods/StripePayments/StripePayments/StripePayments/Source/PaymentHandler/STPPaymentHandler.swift:523:31: error: variable binding in a condition requires an initializer
                if let setupIntent, error == nil {
                                  ^
    /Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fsxrcxlpwvnsjwaxkmmacfdixrme/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/StripePayments.build/Objects-normal/arm64/STPIntentActionVerifyWithMicrodeposits.dia:1:1: warning: Could not read serialized diagnostics file: error("Invalid diagnostics signature") (in target 'StripePayments' from project 'Pods')
    Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
    /Users/apple/StudioProjects/test2/ios/Pods/StripePayments/StripePayments/StripePayments/Source/PaymentHandler/STPPaymentHandler.swift:301:28: error: variable binding in a condition requires an initializer
                guard let self else {
                               ^
    /Users/apple/StudioProjects/test2/ios/Pods/StripePayments/StripePayments/StripePayments/Source/PaymentHandler/STPPaymentHandler.swift:520:28: error: variable binding in a condition requires an initializer
                guard let self else {
                               ^
    /Users/apple/StudioProjects/test2/ios/Pods/StripePayments/StripePayments/StripePayments/Source/PaymentHandler/STPPaymentHandler.swift:523:31: error: variable binding in a condition requires an initializer
                if let setupIntent, error == nil {
                                  ^
    /Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fsxrcxlpwvnsjwaxkmmacfdixrme/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/StripePayments.build/Objects-normal/arm64/STPKlarnaLineItem.dia:1:1: warning: Could not read serialized diagnostics file: error("Invalid diagnostics signature") (in target 'StripePayments' from project 'Pods')
    Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
    /Users/apple/StudioProjects/test2/ios/Pods/StripePayments/StripePayments/StripePayments/Source/PaymentHandler/STPPaymentHandler.swift:301:28: error: variable binding in a condition requires an initializer
                guard let self else {
                               ^
    /Users/apple/StudioProjects/test2/ios/Pods/StripePayments/StripePayments/StripePayments/Source/PaymentHandler/STPPaymentHandler.swift:520:28: error: variable binding in a condition requires an initializer
                guard let self else {
                               ^
    /Users/apple/StudioProjects/test2/ios/Pods/StripePayments/StripePayments/StripePayments/Source/PaymentHandler/STPPaymentHandler.swift:523:31: error: variable binding in a condition requires an initializer
                if let setupIntent, error == nil {
                                  ^
    /Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fsxrcxlpwvnsjwaxkmmacfdixrme/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/StripePayments.build/Objects-normal/arm64/STPMandateCustomerAcceptanceParams.dia:1:1: warning: Could not read serialized diagnostics file: error("Invalid diagnostics signature") (in target 'StripePayments' from project 'Pods')
    Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
    /Users/apple/StudioProjects/test2/ios/Pods/StripePayments/StripePayments/StripePayments/Source/PaymentHandler/STPPaymentHandler.swift:301:28: error: variable binding in a condition requires an initializer
                guard let self else {
                               ^
    /Users/apple/StudioProjects/test2/ios/Pods/StripePayments/StripePayments/StripePayments/Source/PaymentHandler/STPPaymentHandler.swift:520:28: error: variable binding in a condition requires an initializer
                guard let self else {
                               ^
    /Users/apple/StudioProjects/test2/ios/Pods/StripePayments/StripePayments/StripePayments/Source/PaymentHandler/STPPaymentHandler.swift:523:31: error: variable binding in a condition requires an initializer
                if let setupIntent, error == nil {
                                  ^
    /Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fsxrcxlpwvnsjwaxkmmacfdixrme/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/StripePayments.build/Objects-normal/arm64/STPMandateDataParams.dia:1:1: warning: Could not read serialized diagnostics file: error("Invalid diagnostics signature") (in target 'StripePayments' from project 'Pods')
    Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
    /Users/apple/StudioProjects/test2/ios/Pods/StripePayments/StripePayments/StripePayments/Source/PaymentHandler/STPPaymentHandler.swift:301:28: error: variable binding in a condition requires an initializer
                guard let self else {
                               ^
    /Users/apple/StudioProjects/test2/ios/Pods/StripePayments/StripePayments/StripePayments/Source/PaymentHandler/STPPaymentHandler.swift:520:28: error: variable binding in a condition requires an initializer
                guard let self else {
                               ^
    /Users/apple/StudioProjects/test2/ios/Pods/StripePayments/StripePayments/StripePayments/Source/PaymentHandler/STPPaymentHandler.swift:523:31: error: variable binding in a condition requires an initializer
                if let setupIntent, error == nil {
                                  ^
    /Users/apple/StudioProjects/test2/ios/Pods/StripePayments/StripePayments/StripePayments/Source/Internal/API Bindings/APIRequest.swift:56:42: error: variable binding in a condition requires an initializer
                    guard let responseObject else {
                                             ^
    /Users/apple/StudioProjects/test2/ios/Pods/StripePayments/StripePayments/StripePayments/Source/Internal/API Bindings/APIRequest.swift:98:42: error: variable binding in a condition requires an initializer
                    guard let responseObject else {
                                             ^
    /Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fsxrcxlpwvnsjwaxkmmacfdixrme/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/StripePayments.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Analytic+Payments.dia:1:1: warning: Could not read serialized diagnostics file: error("Invalid diagnostics signature") (in target 'StripePayments' from project 'Pods')
    Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
    /Users/apple/StudioProjects/test2/ios/Pods/StripePayments/StripePayments/StripePayments/Source/Internal/API Bindings/APIRequest.swift:56:42: error: variable binding in a condition requires an initializer
                    guard let responseObject else {
                                             ^
    /Users/apple/StudioProjects/test2/ios/Pods/StripePayments/StripePayments/StripePayments/Source/Internal/API Bindings/APIRequest.swift:98:42: error: variable binding in a condition requires an initializer
                    guard let responseObject else {
                                             ^
    /Users/apple/StudioProjects/test2/ios/Pods/StripePayments/StripePayments/StripePayments/Source/PaymentHandler/STPPaymentHandler.swift:301:28: error: variable binding in a condition requires an initializer
                guard let self else {
                               ^
    /Users/apple/StudioProjects/test2/ios/Pods/StripePayments/StripePayments/StripePayments/Source/PaymentHandler/STPPaymentHandler.swift:520:28: error: variable binding in a condition requires an initializer
                guard let self else {
                               ^
    /Users/apple/StudioProjects/test2/ios/Pods/StripePayments/StripePayments/StripePayments/Source/PaymentHandler/STPPaymentHandler.swift:523:31: error: variable binding in a condition requires an initializer
                if let setupIntent, error == nil {
                                  ^
    /Users/apple/StudioProjects/test2/ios/Pods/StripeFinancialConnections/StripeFinancialConnections/StripeFinancialConnections/Source/Native/NetworkingLinkSignupPane/NetworkingLinkSignupViewController.swift:291:62: error: unable to infer complex closure return type; add explicit type to disambiguate
                                    let didPrefillEmailAddress = {
                                                                 ^
                                                                   () -> <#Result#> in 
    /Users/apple/StudioProjects/test2/ios/Pods/StripeFinancialConnections/StripeFinancialConnections/StripeFinancialConnections/Source/Native/NetworkingLinkSignupPane/NetworkingLinkSignupViewController.swift:291:62: error: unable to infer complex closure return type; add explicit type to disambiguate
                                    let didPrefillEmailAddress = {
                                                                 ^
                                                                   () -> <#Result#> in 
    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning
    note: Build preparation complete
    note: Building targets in dependency order
    warning: Capabilities for Signing & Capabilities may not function correctly because its entitlements use a placeholder team ID. To resolve this, select a development team in the Runner editor. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')

    Result bundle written to path:
        /var/folders/s3/qg6_sd_x7v9c5p0xzgwd3sjr0000gn/T/flutter_tools.J74G6G/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirNRJtwQ/temporary_xcresult_bundle


Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Unable to infer complex closure return type; add explicit type to disambiguate
/Users/apple/StudioProjects/test2/ios/Pods/StripeFinancialConnections/StripeFinancialConnections/StripeFinancialConnections/Source/Native/NetworkingLinkSignupPane/NetworkingLinkSignupViewController.swift:290:61

Uncategorized (Xcode): Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Variable binding in a condition requires an initializer
/Users/apple/StudioProjects/test2/ios/Pods/StripePayments/StripePayments/StripePayments/Source/Internal/API%20Bindings/APIRequest.swift:55:41

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Variable binding in a condition requires an initializer
/Users/apple/StudioProjects/test2/ios/Pods/StripePayments/StripePayments/StripePayments/Source/Internal/API%20Bindings/APIRequest.swift:97:41

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Variable binding in a condition requires an initializer
/Users/apple/StudioProjects/test2/ios/Pods/StripePayments/StripePayments/StripePayments/Source/PaymentHandler/STPPaymentHandler.swift:300:27

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Variable binding in a condition requires an initializer
/Users/apple/StudioProjects/test2/ios/Pods/StripePayments/StripePayments/StripePayments/Source/PaymentHandler/STPPaymentHandler.swift:519:27

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Variable binding in a condition requires an initializer
/Users/apple/StudioProjects/test2/ios/Pods/StripePayments/StripePayments/StripePayments/Source/PaymentHandler/STPPaymentHandler.swift:522:30

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 13.
```

Comment: Why is your Flutter version so old?

Comment: i had to downgrade it for xcode 13.2.1 it was showing error after flutter doctor command

Comment: @danish, were you able to fix this error? I've the same error and I don't know how to fix it.